# An Error occured while compiling Linux Kernel 2.6 with a new System Call

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, makefile

I added a new System Call in the Linux Kernel 2.6.33 including all the essential user-side and kernel-side parts, but while compiling I got the follwing error:

```
arch/x86/built-in.o: In function `sys_call_table':
(.rodata+0x724): undefined reference to `sys_my_sys_call'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
```

I tried to change kernal version (2.6.32.21) but error always occurs.
Let's show the simple code of "Hello! World." syscall:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long sys_hello(void)
{
    printk("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to link the object code (from your new `my_sys_call.c`) that you should have added. BTWX, 2.6.33 is ancient. Current kernel is 3.17!

Comment: Plenty of android (2.3/2.4) and other embedded stuff still runs 2.6.32. It's a long term support version, still being actively maintained.

Comment: It's still used in old linux version, Lubuntu 10.04 for example, and all non-PAE machines don't run newest versions. The code is a simple "Hello! World." syscall.

Comment: I've followed this simple guide to add a system call:  http://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/adding-hello-world-system-call-to-linux/

Comment: i know this is a year ago, but have you figured it out?